# keep me amazed OR keep me amazing?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Recently, I have written somewhere.

> Your offers are amazing. Keep me amazing!

I think it should be

> keep me amazed

as [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/62718/45919)  post suggests.
Still I am confused about it. Which of them is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is something that I can imagine a native English speaker saying. But both are grammatical, with different meanings.

I suspect that what you meant to say is "Keep amazing me!" - an instruction to your readers that they (the subject)  should carry on amazing you (the object).

"Keep me amazed" would have a similar meaning: "Keep me in the state of being amazed (by sending me amazing things)".

"Keep me amazing" would mean "Keep me in the state of being amazing". Your friends might think that you are amazing, but this is nothing to do with things amazing you - it is a description of you.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazed](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/amazed): feeling or showing great surprise.

[Amazing](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/Amazing): causing great surprise or wonder : causing amazement

"Amaze" is one of a number of verbs that have similar adjective forms, one to describe the quality of *being*, and the other to describe the quality of *causing* or *creating*:

> *Surprised/Surprising*
>
> *Astounded/Astounding*
>
> *Enraged/Enraging*

and so on.  In general, the pattern is the *-ed* form describes the quality of being or having that emotion, while the *-ing* form describes the quality of causing or creating that emotion.  Examples:

> I was *uplifted* by the candidate's speech / the candidate's speech was *uplifting*.
>
> She was *exhausted* by the long run / The long run was *exhausting*.

You have to be careful not to confuse the adjective form of these verbs with their past-tense or present-continuous tense forms.  For example, you can say:

> Your offers *amazed* me!
>
> This hike is *exhausting* me!

Also the pattern is not consistent across all verbs like this.  For example, the adjective of "enjoy" is "enjoyable* (to cause or create joy) and not "enjoyed" or "enjoying" (both of which are verbs)